# Error: undefined function user/2 when running mix phoenix.server

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I created this module:

```
defmodule Discuss.Topic do
    user Discuss.Web, :model

    schema "topics" do
        field :title, :string
    end

    def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
        struct
        |> cast(params, [:title])
        |> validate_required([:title])
    end
end
```

and I got this error when using `mix phoenix.server`

```
== Compilation error in file web/models/topic.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/models/topic.ex:2: undefined function user/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:229: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/7
```

Any idea of what's happening? I'm new to Phoenix and Elixir.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ consider using [_formatter_](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Format.html#content), 4 spaces for indent are not idiomatic; this makes the code way harder to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
user Discuss.Web, :model
   ^
   |
  here
```

should be

```
use Discuss.Web, :model
```

### UPDATE

Since "web" should be a thin layer that just offloads HTTP and WebSocket, and delegate the jobs to the underlying business logic, Phoenix no longer consider models be a part of the web layer. So instead of `use Discuss.Web, :model`, you should `use Ecto.Schema`.

By the way, the web layer now contains only controllers, views, channels and the router.

Comment: You deserve 1000 upvotes. I read those files over and over again trying to find any typos... Thank you!

Comment: By the way, the current Phoenix framework does not treat models (or should I say schemas) to be a fixed part of "web", so instead of `use Discuss.Web, :model`, you can simply `use Ecto.Schema`.

Comment: @AdautoPinheiro if the answer helped, you are supposed to mark it with a green checkmark (below the score.)